# Variant of toEqual that works with class properties in the same way that it works with class methods

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, class-properties

This is the scenario. The first class has a method `getName`, and the second class has a class property `getName`. The first class works with `toEqual`, and the second class does not.

```
class Person01 {
    constructor(name) { this.name = name; }
    getName() { return this.name; }
}

class Person02 {
    constructor(name) { this.name = name; }
    getName = () => { return this.name; }
}

const testCases = [
    [
        // passes
        new Person01('Alan', 'Kay'),
        new Person01('Alan', 'Kay'),
    ], 
    [
        // fails due to class properties
        new Person02('Alan', 'Kay'),
        new Person02('Alan', 'Kay'),
    ]
];

describe('when one class has the same values that another class has', () =>
    testCases.forEach(pair =>
        it('is considered to be equal to that class', () =>
            expect(pair[0]).toEqual(pair[1]))));
```

This is the failure message for the second class.

```
Expected: {"firstName": "Alan", "getName": [Function anonymous], "lastName": "Kay"} 
Received: {"firstName": "Alan", "getName": [Function anonymous], "lastName": "Kay"}
```

Our current workaround is to run `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` on the actual and expected values.

What we're looking for instead is a variant of `toEqual` that works the same way with class properties as it does with class methods.

Here is our babel.config.js file.

```
module.exports = function (api) {

  api.env();

  const plugins = [
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
  ];

  return {
    plugins,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that function class properties are created per instance...

...so `toEqual` fails since each instance has a different set of function properties.

---

One option is to create a [custom matcher](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers), but that is tricky since `toEqual` [is doing a lot](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/2fc468c5fb236b081c081b90735af89f410bb79f/packages/expect/src/jasmineUtils.ts#L63-L194).

Another option is to just filter the function properties before using `toEqual`:

```js
const filterFunctions = (obj) => 
  Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(k => typeof obj[k] !== 'function')
    .reduce((a, k) => { a[k] = obj[k]; return a; }, {});

describe('when one class has the same values that another class has', () =>
  testCases.forEach(pair =>
      it('is considered to be equal to that class', () =>
          expect(filterFunctions(pair[0])).toEqual(filterFunctions(pair[1])))));  // Success!
```

Comment: One difficulty here is that `filterFunctions` will also filter methods.

Comment: Also, a complete answer needs a recursive step to filter out functions in nested objects.